# How can I predict whether I will be able to take on a specific enemy or group?

Tags: the-secret-world

I know in many other MMORPGs, it is standard for health bars or other parts of an enemy's information to be marked in different colors depending on how difficult that encounter will be. Is there any similar system for The Secret World?

I noticed that the enemy's name can vary in color, but does *not* specify this information. The normal basic zombies and more difficult zombies both are red, while quest target enemies are generally in orange. This was throwing me off for a while.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to look at the dot to the left of the name - the color of that will indicate how safe it is.  White is and even match, blues and greens will probably be pretty easy, orange and yellow are going to be tough, and red means "Run away!".

The TYPE of dot indicates linking behavior (a single dot is normal, three dots indicate monsters that move in crowds, skulls and crowns indicate lieutenant or rare type monsters).

The color of the name indicates how aggressive the monster is.